# Disable/enable clientside all checkboxes in a Telerik RadTreeView

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radtreeview

I need to disable all checkboxes that I have in telerik RadTree. How I could achieve that?

Trick is, these are not HTML controls but seem to be something imitating these via images, CSS and javascript. For instance, HTML for a RadTreeView node looks like:

```
  <div class="rtMid">
  <span class="rtSp"></span>
  <span class="rtMinus"></span>
  <span class="rtUnchecked"></span>
  <span class="rtIn">Item text</span>
  </div>
```

Best, Askar

Comment: Do you need this done server side or client side?

Comment: client, since server should be pretty easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply redefine its `onclick` javascript event so it doesn't fire.

This is supposed to work in every browser:

```
onclickEvent = "if (event.cancelable) {event.preventDefault();}else {event.returnValue = false;} return false;";
```

This is what I think is the best cross-browser solution:

```
onclickEvent = "this.checked = !this.checked;";
```

Comment: Add this attribute from code behind, to every RadTreeView node you want to prevent from being checked.